# How to replace current page content on user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mediawiki-api

I am creating a search engine of sorts, using the Wikipedia API to query content. As it currently stands, the user can make a search input and the page returns the top 10 results with links and snippets. I run into difficulty when the user makes another search, in which case the page simply appends the original search results again. I have tried using replaceWith() and html(), but they either prevent the search results from coming through at all (if I put them within the event handler), or they don't get triggered (if they are outside the event handler). I am hoping to achieve a result where the user can make another input and the page will replace the current content with the new search results.

Here is what I have currently:

JS:

```
var results = [];

$("#search").on("keydown", "#searchinput", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    var searchParameter = encodeURIComponent(this.value);
    var link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchParameter + "&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*";
    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {
      for (var key in data) {
        results.push(data[key]);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $("#results").append("<div class=\"resultContent\">" + "<h2>" + "<a href=\"" + results[3][i] + "\">" + results[1][i] + "</a>" + "</h2>" + "<p>" + results[2][i] + "<br/>" + "</p>")
      }
    })
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random">Feeling Bold? Click Here for a Random Article</a>

<div id="search">
  <span>Search:</span>
  <input type="text" id="searchinput" autocomplete="off"></input>
</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the current results just before your loop:

```
$("#results").empty();    
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     $("#results").append("<div class=\"resultContent\">" + "<h2>" + "<a href=\"" + results[3][i] + "\">" + results[1][i] + "</a>" + "</h2>" + "<p>" + results[2][i] + "<br/>" + "</p>")
}
```

Comment: This prevented the content from duplicating, but it does not replace the current content with the new search results

Comment: You have the same content because you are pushing latest results into results array and then you always show first 10 results only. Try to reset results array before the loop: results = [];

Comment: Your first answer actually helped me get to that solution - thanks!